# Sanitize::html with accents CakePHP2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, sanitization, diacritics, sanitize

I was using this to save my data into the Database:

```
$this->request->data['Post']['body'] = utf8_decode($this->request->data['Post']['body']);
```

Like that, i could save into my DB some "special" characters like the ones with accents:
áéíóú without any problem.

Then, i tried to protect my application from HTML and SQL injections and i used Sanitization like this:

```
$this->request->data['Post']['body'] = Sanitize::html($this->request->data['Post']['body']);
```

So now my text is stored on the database like this:

```
á = &aacute;
é = &eacute;
í = &iacute; ...etc
```

And i dont want that. Also, my field on the DB has a maximun of characters and this doesn't help.

I have also tried to use the options param at sanitize with encode = true, encode = false or encode = 'utf8' but nothing seems to change.

What should i do?
Thanks.

## UPDATE 1

I have also tried to use htmlentities function on my controller but it inserts this in my database instead of á:

```
&Atilde;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Cake to save your data (i.e., using `save()` not `query()`) then you are protected against SQL injection. It escapes values automatically.

As stated in the docs, [`Sanitize::html()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/sanitize#method-Sanitizehtml) will convert characters to HTML entities, such as `&gt;`, `&aacute;`, etc. You probably shouldn't use it unless you specifically want HTML entities. Cake will take care of storing your accents in the database just fine if you have the proper encoding on your app and tables.

Comment: Ok, then i should just use h($myText) in my Views to protect it from HTML injections right?

Comment: Ok, i can treat it on my view as my body containts created URL's on HTML format (<a href="bb">aaa</a>) and it destroys it.
I have also tried to use htmlentities on my controller but it saves me this on the database: &Atilde; instead of á

Comment: You could just `Sanitize::stripTags()` if you don't want to store HTML. `h()` won't help you there. It just converts characters to entities, kind of like `Sanitize::html()` was doing.

Comment: Now i did this: utf8_decode(Sanitize::stripTags($this->request->data['Post']['body']));
And it doesn't work. If i insert something like this: <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html"> 
It redirects the page on the view.

Comment: `Sanitize::stripTags()` requires that you tell it which tags to remove (second argument). If you just want to strip all tags, try PHP's `strip_tags()` instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks!! I know its php basic but i have always used htmlentities for it and i didn't know this function :)

Comment: as you pointed out, use h() in the views and absolute nothing else and you are definitly and 100% fine. no additional stuff required.